# RestTemplate - how to don't load response body

Tags: java, http, resttemplate

I have to send a lot of http requests to third-party server in my project. And in each response is about 30kb of html. So, I want to save traffic. Is there any way to don't load response? Now I'm using RestTemplate for sending requests, but if needed to use something else,  it's not a problem. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Now I'm sending requests like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> sendPost(Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> params, String... url)
{
    String urlStr = url.length != 0 ? url[0] : BASE_URL + "index.php";
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(mapToString(params), mapToHeaders(headers));
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    return restTemplate.postForEntity(urlStr, entity, String.class);
}
```

Comment: how do you make your http request? example of code.